# Htaccess - Use query string as folder name in redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I´m trying to redirect from

https://example.com/?s=QUERY

to

https://example.com/search/keyword/QUERY/search-in/product/cat-in/all/search-other/product

I tried with the following code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^s=(\w+)$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://example.com/%1  [R=302,L]
```

Which gives me this result

https://example.com/search/keyword/QUERY?s=QUERY/search-in/product/cat-in/all/search-other/product

For some reason, I´m getting the query string duplicate and with the parameter name in between.
What should I fix in this code to get only the query string and not the rest?

Comment: End your substitution URL with a question mark, or use the [`QSD` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd).